# Markov chain Monte Carlo sampling using CDFs instead of PDFs

Tags: sampling, montecarlo, markov-chains, mcmc

I wonder if there is any MCMC sampling method which uses the definition of the multivariate target CDF instead of the target PDF; however, I may use a proposal PDF.

I would like to use Metropolis-Hastings but it is not possible because the calculation of the acceptance ratio is defined in terms of the target PDF.

I say this because it is impossible for me to obtain the PDF associated to certain CDF without doing some kind of numerical approximation which may bias my simulation; also, my CDF might be not continuous, and therefore I cannot differenciate it to obtain the PDF

Regards!

Comment: I think that http://stats.stackexchange.com/ could be a better place where to ask

Comment: My advice is to use a histogram to get the PDF out of real data rather than differentiating the CDF